# typescript + react - mixed variable in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, ecmascript-6

I have this code in my react application, as per interface, a variable `items` should be an array.
But, in my initial state, there it is initialized as `null` (for I need as `null` as initial state).

Within the interface declaration I could have written `?Array`, but it would mean, that the key `items` may not be in the state at all - and provided that this key is present within the object, it is going to be an array.

What are options? Is my architecture bad? Or how to declare required variable as mixed array|null?

```
declare interface StateInterface {
    items: Array
}


class MyComponent extends Component {
    state: StateInterface = {
        items: null
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize it to an empty array:

```
  class MyComponent extends Component<{}, StateInterface> {
    constructor() {
     this.state = { items: [] };
    }
 }
```